# VBA - For looping through dates, transfer to another worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to basically copy and paste four columns from one worksheet to another worksheet.  Two of these columns contain dates, and I've tried a basic for loop to run through the information and copy it to the next worksheet.

```
For i = 2 To table4.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    table5.Cells(i, 1).Value = table4.Cells(i, 1).Value
    table5.Cells(i, 2).Value = table4.Cells(i, 5).Value
    table5.Cells(i, 3).Value = table4.Cells(i, 6).Value
    table5.Cells(i, 4).Value = table4.Cells(i, 7).Value
Next
```

Yet when I do this, the dates don't appear on table5.  Rather, eight hashtags ######## fill up the space with no numbers at all.  I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, or if there's a better way to do this.  The dates on table4 are in traditional format ex. 8/7/2015 if that makes any difference.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do the cells you copy contain any formulas, or are they just raw numbers? Might be that it copies the formula and it doesn't work in the new table? Not sure though.

Comment: Have you tried increasing the width of the columns where the #'s appear?

Comment: Sounds like your columns are simply too narrow to show the data. When Excel encounters that, it shows #'s to avoid someone misenterpreting $1,000,000 as $1,000 when it gets cut off. Ensure your format for the pasted values is date format, and that the font is small enough, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Your code works.

Make sure that:
- the column is wide enough
- your table5 column 1,2,3,4 cell format is set to the same date format as table4 column 1,5,6,7

Comment: It definitely sounds like an issue with the columns not being wide enough. OP please increase the width of the columns and see if that fixes the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the others that it's a column width issue. To fix it automatically, try this:

```
For i = 2 To table4.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    table5.Cells(i, 1).Value = table4.Cells(i, 1).Value
    table5.Cells(i, 2).Value = table4.Cells(i, 5).Value
    table5.Cells(i, 3).Value = table4.Cells(i, 6).Value
    table5.Cells(i, 4).Value = table4.Cells(i, 7).Value
Next
table5.Range("A1:D1").Columns.AutoFit
```

The `.AutoFit` will adjust each column to the minimum width necessary to display all the characters in the widest cell.